# Tmap: The shape only contains empty units

Tags: r, tmap

I am trying to plot layers based in queries with tmap, with something like:

```
tm_shape(data%>% filter(column=="some_data"))
```

But when the query returns an empty sf the following meassage appears:

```
Error: The shape data%>% filter(column=="some_data") only contains empty units (after reprojection).
```

Is there any way I can deal with these empty sf?

Comment: It helps to add the "R" tag to questions about R packages.

Comment: What do you want to happen if you are trying to map data with no rows? A warning, a blank plot? Why not create the filtered data and check its `nrow()` and then either plot it or do something else?

Comment: I agree with spacedman. Also try `tm_shape(data%>% dplyr::filter(column=="some_data"))`, maybe there is a package loaded with a function with the same name

Comment: I'll try both. Thanks!